# the best solution for two variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are two variables for a problem z.

Requirement:

variable x : less better

variable y : more better

```
               x     |      y
solution A     4255  |      49595
solution B     9187  |      76662
solution C    14587  |      98262
solution D    22604  |      125746
```

So which solution is the best? I do not have any clue. Which tools should I choose? How do I solve this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
               x     |      y
basement       0     |      0
solution A     4255  |      49595
solution B     9187  |      76662
solution C    14587  |      98262
solution D    22604  |      125746
```

All data is calculated by comparing basement.

x = 4255 is compared with x=0. And x = 14587 is compared with x=0 either. Other data uses same rule.

Comment: What makes it better to have a small $x$? What makes it better to have a large $y$? Perhaps if you look closer into the underlying problem--which you've told us nothing about--it will be clearer how to tell when one pair of $x$ and $y$ values is better than another.

Comment: There is a basement for all data. All data is generated by comparing the basement.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not any kind of useful information about the problem. It doesn't even explain why we want a smaller $x$ instead of a larger $x$.

Comment: Oh, caz x is a kind of tax. So it is better to smaller for company.

Comment: So does $y-x$ describe how good a solution is? Or do the variables influence the "goodness" of a solution in some other way?

Comment: Yes, that should be no definition. It's just a "hope" which is less tax and more profit.

Comment: So you were asking a wrong question. You really want to optimize $y-x$, and this is an ordinary one-variable problem, for which we needn't have to give you any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer to this question, because there is no unique order in 2D.

You might say, I will take the largest $y-x$, as this favors large $y$ and small $x$. Then D is the best.

But you might as well consider $y/x$ for the same reason, and conclude $A$.

With this particular dataset, you can find criteria for which any solution is the "best".

Comment: Actually, there is a basement. But It seems not helpful, either. And it is all data already. So the data is lost requirements to get best solution?

Comment: @NickDong: you don't seem to have understood my answer.

Comment: I understand now, after reading @Davik K 's comment. There is no criteria for choosing `y-x` or `y/x`. That should be no answer for the "best".